# Objects that mutually need each other

Tags: oop

I am in the situation when two classes (let's call **A** and **B**) are related to each other (their methods rely on the data of the other one) but the IS-A relation is not appropriate. I could use composition, so that both objects have fields that store the other object. But this seems to be ugly for me. What I currently do is to create another class **C** containing the objects from **A** and **B** via composition and when I want to call a method of class **A**, I pass the object **B**. My problems with this approach:

- I need to pass one object to the other so it starts to resemble a simple function argument passing instead of the OOP approach where the object encapsulates its data
- if I need to change something, I might have to modify the code of both classes **A** and **B**, which is not a good point for code reuse

What do you recommend?

**Example**

```
class Mesh:
  method: plot(this, Solver)
          {
             plot data from class Solver // need to pass a Solver object, so the class is not self-contained
          }
  method: intersect(this, Domain)
          {
             do sth // depends on Domain, so we need to pass it
          }

class Domain:
  method: plot(this)
          {
             plot data from own data // no problem
          }
  method: selectVertex(this, Mesh)
          {
             do sth // depends on Mesh, so we need to pass it
          }
```

Thank you,
Zoltan

Comment: In general this is not a good idea to have two objects mutually dependent on each other. But, hard to say anything more without you providing some concrete information/code.

Comment: Mutual composition is not a good idea rather a clue that your classes are so related and, maybe, they must be just one class with the attributes of A and B. But, without a concrete code is difficult.

Comment: Yes, they are related but if they would be one class, then I would have the temptation to put almost everything into one class, which is not very advantageous in OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection except for the problem of too many layers of indirection" - David Wheeler.

You tried to add another layer of indirection but it didn't solve your problem. So there is a thing that is fundamentally wrong.

Here is my point of view:

When you have 2 objects that mutually depends on each other it may imply that 2 classes should be merged together into one bigger class which in turn produces a bigger object that has functionalities of both.

Why not? There are many ways to model your domain business in Object-Oriented way and your approach may no longer be suitable as your domain business grow.